# Inconsistent fetch by spark kafka consumer

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, kafka-consumer-api

I have written a code to fetch records from kafka into spark. I have come across some strange behaviour. It is consuming in inconsistent order.

```
 val conf = new SparkConf()
  .setAppName("Test Data")
  .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "192.168.0.40")
  .set("spark.cassandra.connection.keep_alive_ms", "20000")
  .set("spark.executor.memory", "1g")
  .set("spark.driver.memory", "2g")
  .set("spark.submit.deployMode", "cluster")
  .set("spark.executor.instances", "4")
  .set("spark.executor.cores", "3")
  .set("spark.cores.max", "12")
  .set("spark.driver.cores", "4")
  .set("spark.ui.port", "4040")
  .set("spark.streaming.backpressure.enabled", "true")
  .set("spark.streaming.kafka.maxRatePerPartition", "30")
  .set("spark.local.dir", "//tmp//")
  .set("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "/tmp/hive/")
  .set("hive.exec.scratchdir", "/tmp/hive2")

val spark = SparkSession
  .builder
  .appName("Test Data")
  .config(conf)
  .getOrCreate()

import spark.implicits._

val sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(conf)
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(10))
val topics = Map("topictest" -> 1)
val kafkaParams = Map[String, String](
  "zookeeper.connect" -> "192.168.0.40:2181",
  "group.id" -> "=groups",
  "auto.offset.reset" -> "smallest")

val kafkaStream =  KafkaUtils.createStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](ssc, kafkaParams, topics, StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER)
}

kafkaStream.foreachRDD(rdd =>
  {
    if (!rdd.partitions.isEmpty) {
      try {
        println("Count of rows " + rdd.count())
      } catch {
        case e: Exception => e.printStackTrace
      }
    } else {
      println("blank rdd")
    }
  })
```

So, Initially I produced 10 million records in kafka. Now producer is stopped and then started Spark Consumer Application. I checked Spark UI, initially I received 700,000-900,000 records per batch(every 10 seconds ) per stream, afterwards started getting 4-6K records per batch. So wanted to understand why the fetch count fell so badly despite the fact that data is present in Kafka so instead of giving 4k per batch , I'am open to consumer directly big size batch. What can be done and how ?

Thanks,

Comment: What are ur kafka consumer configurations? How many partitions u have in the topic?

Comment: What is the kafka fetch size set and let us know the number of consumers you have spawned in a consumer group and the number of partitions for a topic. Also, let us know if you have a single group of consumers?

Comment: What is the "max.poll.records" set in your configs?

Comment: @IndraneelBende  I have 50 partition in kafka topic

Comment: @PhaniKumarYadavilli - No fetch size just 10 second streaming window . 5 consumers are consuming data from 50 partitions of a topic. Yes, we are fetching through single group.

Comment: @PhaniKumarYadavilli - As we can see in the code, I have not set any such paramater in the config "max.poll.records" . So default values are running as of now.

Comment: In your example you said u had produced, 10 million records and then stopped producing further. Can you produce and consume at the same time, and see if that makes a difference. My point is as u said initially it got 700,000-900,000 in earlier batches, it could simply be the case, that it was out of records.

Comment: Yes I can produce and consume at the same time and yes it makes a difference by giving reasonable batch size not very large or small , but my testing is for a case when data is already present in kafka and my spark job runs after some time so there I want consistent batch of records